# Strange cross-cast. How is it possible?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, static-cast

I'm trying to understand how does this strange example work:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        virtual void f() {std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl;}
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        void f() {std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl;}
        void h() {std::cout << "B::h()" << std::endl;}
};

class C : public A {
    public:
        void f() {std::cout << "C::f()" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    A* ap1 = new C();
    auto bp1 = static_cast<B*>(ap1);
    bp1->h();

    A* ap2 = new C();
    auto bp2 = dynamic_cast<B*>(ap2);
    bp2->h();

    return 0;
}
```

As a result of both casts it successfully calls B::h().
Full output is:

```
B::h()
B::h()
```

How is it possible?

Comment: When a `dynamic_cast` fails to cast a pointer, it returns a `nullptr`. Calling functions on a nullptr is undefined behavior

Comment: You can't turn `A` into a `B`. Everything else counts for _undefined behavior_.

Comment: I think you are surviving because `h()` doesn't use `this`.

Comment: I understand that this is not valid use of type casts, and that bp2 will be nullptr, but I'm trying to understand why it looks like it is working.

Comment: Look up one comment, but in truth Undefined Behaviour can do whatever it wants from look like it works to rain unicorn ASCII art.

Comment: The magic of undefined behavior, where anything can happen. Even appearing to work. Both "work" probably because the method doesn't actually use any information in the object instance. So there's no reason for the method to use the invalid `this` pointer.

Comment: Alright, but how does existence of virtual function can affect this behaviour?

Comment: At that point it should not compile. No virtual functions so polymorphism isn't available for `dynamic_cast`

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I was wrong on this difference with virtual function, I can not reproduce it anymore.

Comment: That's undefined behaivour for you. Here today, gone in a flash.

Comment: @rzhurov _"Alright, but how does existence of virtual function can affect this behaviour?"_ What specific _behavior_ actually? It's **undefined**. So that question is moot.

Comment: Fun fact: the Clang/LLVM compiler system can't run under sanitizers because it does this *deliberately*.

Comment: i do not know why you cycled on the undefined behavior. In this particular case the behavior is well defined. it calls a non-virtual member function which doe not use any members of the class. The resulting pointer is of type 'B' as provided by its type. It does not matter what value it takes. The compiler will call teh B::h() even if it NULL. This is intended behavior.  It will be undefined if you call a virtual function or will crash if it accesses class members. But other than that it is perfectly legal.

Comment: @Serge: The standard says the expression to the left of `->` is evaluated. The standard even says in a footnote, "If the class member access expression is evaluated, the subexpression evaluation happens even if the result is unnecessary to determine the value of the entire postfix expression, for example if the id-expression denotes a static member".  So the example is undefined behavior, and the compiler is allowed to do something broken (or not depending on what someone considers broken).

Comment: And strictly speaking, undefined behavior occurs at the point of the `static_cast` so after that point all bets are off anyway.

Comment: @Serge: The language specification does not say that it is OK to perform a class method call through an invalid pointer if the method is non-virtual and does not access any data members of the class. It is true that the standard took some steps in that direction, but they have never been completed. In modern C++ it is always illegal to invoke a method through an invalid pointer, regardless of anything else.

Comment: @AnT the standard does not say that it is not OK either.

Comment: @MichaelBurr yes, static_cast behavior is undefined in this case, but there is nothing in the standard which prevents calling the member function based on invalid pointer. Implementation-wise the function itself is called with 'this' passed to it in some way.  So, as soon as 'this' is not used to access anything, it should work (as a static function).

Comment: @Serge: What makes you think that "there is nothing in the standard which prevents calling the member function based on invalid pointer"? The standard explicitly says (in section [expr.ref]) that the left-hand side of `->` is evaluated (as `(*(ptr).member)`), even when the member being referenced is a static member. So a null pointer is UB. In the case where the pointer is obtained through an invalid `static_cast`, well then you already have UB and evaluating a pointer obtained through UB is still UB.

Comment: @MichaelBurr it does not say that this behavior should be undefined for illegal pointers. More over, it is interpreted as 'prvalue' for the non-static member functions. And 'prvalue' which is used to compute a 'value' has *no* resulting object.  So, for member functions it is just supposed to call the function despite the value of the pointer.

Comment: @Serge: can you point to something in the standard to explain what you're saying? The part of the standard I'm referring to is C++14 5.2.5 "Class member access" ([expr.ref]). That's where it says the left-hand side of  `->` is evaluated, that `E1->E2` is equivalent to `(*(E1)).E2`, and in a footnote mentions that the eval occurs even if the member being accessed is static. There is also a footnote that mentions that `(*(E1))` is an lvalue, but I'll be honest in saying that I haven't bothered to go through the work to figure out what significance prvalue/lvalue/whatever might have here.

Comment: @MichaelBurr 6.10 (2) talks about prvalue; 8.2.5. (3) is what you mentionedd, 8.2.5.(4.3.2) is about non-static members. BTW, keyword `evaluated` is overused. I understand is as evaluated by the compiler which know nothing about invalid pointers in any case.  Again, i do not have real ieee standard handy and looking in the drarf of 2017-03-21 (N4659)

Comment: @Serge: note that in the examples, `bp1` and `bp2` are actually glvalues, but glvalues readily convert to prvalues when required - as in the case for the left side of the `->` operator. But, I don't see how the left side of `->` being a prvalue means the compiler is required to *not* evaluate the lhs. That C++17 draft says pretty much the same as the C++14 standard: the `E1->E2` expression converts to `(*(E1)).E2` and the expression before the dot is evaluated - even if `E2` is a static member. Therefore if `E1` is a null or  invalid pointer, you have UB.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ok. I think we used off the limit for this discussion here :-), Thanks. This all looks too vague and is prone for interpretations. Has to be clarified in the standard.

Answer (score 3):

A common misconception is that whenever you dereference a `NULL` pointer, you get a `SIGSEGV`. This is untrue. Rather, you get Undefined Behavior.

In particular, if your code dereferences a pointer, the compiler is allowed to optimize as if it were impossible to be `NULL` at that point. Here, the only case where it's possible to get a non-`NULL` pointer out of `dynamic_cast` is if it really is an instance of `B`, so the compiler eliminates the check.

Compile with `-fsanitize=undefined` to get meaningful results:

```
ub.cpp:22:35: runtime error: downcast of address 0x55c9736dcc20 which does not point to an object of type 'B'
0x55c9736dcc20: note: object is of type 'C'
 00 00 00 00  48 fd c3 71 c9 55 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  21 00 00 00
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              vptr for 'C'
ub.cpp:23:11: runtime error: member call on address 0x55c9736dcc20 which does not point to an object of type 'B'
0x55c9736dcc20: note: object is of type 'C'
 00 00 00 00  48 fd c3 71 c9 55 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  21 00 00 00
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              vptr for 'C'
B::h()
ub.cpp:27:11: runtime error: member call on null pointer of type 'struct B'
ub.cpp:27:11: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct B'
[1]    10583 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./ub
```

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is undefined in both cases. Your "successfully calls `B::h()`" is just a particular manifestation of that undefined behavior.

Your first cast `static_cast<B*>(ap1)` produces undefined behavior immediately, just by itself. In order for this downcast to be valid, pointer `ap1` must point to an `A` base subobject of some `B` object. If this is not the case, the behavior is undefined.

Your second downcast has defined behavior, but under these conditions it "fails" the way `dynamic_cast` fails: it returns a null pointer. You nevertheless attempt to call `bp2->h()` through that null pointer. The behavior becomes undefined at that stage.